# Call method in main thread after timertask completes

Tags: java, multithreading, timertask

I have set up a `TimerTask` via `initializeTimerTask()` that runs after a specified time interval.
After the task has finished, I want to call a method in my main thread. How can I achieve this? I guess letting my main thread `wait()` wouldn't work because that task is reoccurring and the initializing method only called once?

Here's my code:

```java
    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        TrackingTask tracker = new TrackingTask();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tracker, 0, interval);    
    }



    class TrackingTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                doMyTracking();

                // TODO: Notify main thread to do some work
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Blocking Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

At the end of the `TrackingTask.run()` method, add a Runnable that contains the "some work that has to be done in the main thread" into the Queue.

In your main method, one possibility is to make an infinite loop and call the `take()` method of the queue and run it to take the task (or wait until there is a task) and run it.

In the main method, for example like this:

```
public static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    yourClassInstance.initializeTimerTask();

    while(true) {
        queue.take().run();
    }

}
```

And in your `TrackingTask` class:

```
class TrackingTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

       doMyTracking();
       queue.add(() -> {
            // Here the stuff that needs to be done in the main thread.
            // The Runnable is added to the queue and then taken and executed in main()
       });
    }   
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this leads to my main thread to do nothing but wait for the queue... but it should be able to do other stuff in the meantime, e.g. when the tracking interval is set to 10 minutes.

Comment: after TrackingTask is executed, is it necessary to execute the "stuff" precisely in the main thread? Then you could just launch a new runnable and not queue.

Comment: Are you updating some kind of a GUI after the TrackingTask is completed and thus you have to execute it on the main (UI) thread?

Comment: No I have no GUI. Just thought it would be "cleaner" if I return to the main thread... But I guess it will also work with a new Runnable. Thanks!